# Jenkins is throwing a hudson.util.IOException2 on a Windows 2008 Server

Tags: git, jenkins, classnotfoundexception

Jenkins is throwing a hudson.util.IOException2 on a Windows 2008 Server.It looks like it is not able to pull in the Web driver code repository from GIT and the Jenkins Workspace directory for this job is empty.

Jenkins Version : Jenkins ver. 1.530
JRE on windows : 1.7.0.60

Solutions tried: Disabling the slave and rebooting it.JRE Versions does not match on the master and slave but I have other machines which has the JRE mismatch and jobs on those slaves still run fine.

```
            Entire Stack trace: 
            ----------
                       Using strategy: Default
                       hudson.util.IOException2: remote file operation failed: c:\Jenkins\workspace\Dirty_Smoke_Test_IE at hudson.remoting.Channel@668df1c3:nybqaapp2
                        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:905)
                        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:882)
                at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.determineRevisionToBuild(GitSCM.java:948)
                at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1114)
                at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1408)
                at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:657)
                at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
                at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:562)
                at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1603)
                at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
                at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
                at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:246)
            Caused by: java.io.IOException: Remote call on nybqaapp2 failed
                at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:723)
                at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:898)
                ... 11 more
            Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to load hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM
                at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader.loadClassFile(RemoteClassLoader.java:305)
                at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader.findClass(RemoteClassLoader.java:231)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
                at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Unknown Source)
                at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getDeclaredSUID(Unknown Source)
                at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$700(Unknown Source)
                at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(Unknown Source)
                at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(Unknown Source)
                at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(Unknown Source)
                at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
                at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
                at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
                at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
                at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
                at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
                at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
                at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
                at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
                at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.deserialize(UserRequest.java:182)
                at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:98)
                at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
                at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
                at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
                at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:63)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
            Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/plugins/git/GitSCMBackwardCompatibility
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
                at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader.loadClassFile(RemoteClassLoader.java:301)
                ... 33 more
            Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.plugins.git.GitSCMBackwardCompatibility
                at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1365)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1315)
                at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1068)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
                at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader$ClassLoaderProxy.fetch4(RemoteClassLoader.java:721)
                at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader$ClassLoaderProxy.fetch3(RemoteClassLoader.java:763)
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1450.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
                at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.perform(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:299)
                at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
                at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into similar issue,

here is how I resolved the issue,  Disabling slave did not work, deleted workspace, disconnected slave and started job ( I do not recall if I enabled the slave manually or it happened automatically). it started working.